# need item URL format for sharepoint socialdataservice.asmx

Tags: javascript, web-services, sharepoint

I am trying to set a list item's rating using SocialDataService.asmx.  The POST response indicates success; however, nothing has actually been updated.  My guess is that the URL format of the item I am trying to update is somehow not what the web service is expecting.  Has anyone had success with this web service/operation?

My code:

attempt 1:

```
var payload = "<url>" + WebFullUrl 
+ "_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Posts')/Items(" + id + ")</url><rating>" 
+ rating + "</rating><title></title><analysisDataEntry></analysisDataEntry>";
```

attempt 2:

```
var payload = "<url>" + WebFullUrl 
+ "Lists/Posts/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + id + "</url><rating>" 
+ rating + "</rating><title></title><analysisDataEntry></analysisDataEntry>";
```

The call ends up looking like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<SetRating xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/SocialDataService">
<url>https:// (site url) /Lists/Posts/DispForm.aspx?ID=2</url>
<rating>4</rating>
<title></title>
<analysisDataEntry></analysisDataEntry>
</SetRating>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and the response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<SetRatingResponse
xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/SharePointPortalServer/SocialDataService">
SetRatingResult>2013-03-27T20:03:33.55</SetRatingResult>
</SetRatingResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

what I just did in a similar situation is to use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and click on the rating in the SharePoint list. You can then see the exact URL that Microsoft uses.